# Graylog How restart backend collector from api?

Tags: api, graylog2

[image]

what should i send in json body to restart backend?

Answer (score 1):

Send the following to the API:

```json
[{"backend":"nxlog","properties":{"restart":true}}]
```

Comment: Could you please add more text of what you are looking for?

Comment: @jhutar This is an answer, not a question. The question asks what to send in the JSON body of a request.

Comment: Oh my, sorry. I have commented and down-voted by mistake.